# Why my aws ec2 instance have two ip addresses?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

On AWS EC2 Console IPv4 address of my instance is shown as `52.**.**.**` which I use to connect via ssh and https. But `ifconfig` of this instance does not show this ip in any of network interfaces. Also, there is a `172.**.**.***` ip in output of `ifconfig` and in name of machine (`ubuntu@172.**.**.***`) but I cant connect using this address via ssh and dont understand what the address it is?

Comment: Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html#concepts-private-addresses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of your home network. You have an address on your computer (call this a private IP address) and a public IP address that the world sees (provided by your router [DSL, Cable Modem, etc.]).

AWS provides you with a virtual network (similar to what you create at home). This virtual network is called a VPC and has its own private address space. All systems inside this VPC receive one or more IP addresses. These addresses are private and can not be accessed from the Internet.

AWS provides an option to add an Internet Gateway (IGW) to your VPC. The IGW supports assigning public IP addresses to your instance in addition to the private IP address. This is the public IP address that you see.

AWS also provides another option which is the NAT Gateway. This is very similar to the Internet Gateway above in that it provides IP address translation but only for systems that connect from the private IP space to the Internet. There is no reverse mapping - private systems are not assigned a public IP address.

AWS Public IP addresses come in two types. The shared public IP address, which is assigned to your system on startup. If you stop your instance and then start at a  later date, you may or may not get a different IP addresses. AWS just assigns you a public IP address from a shared pool of addresses.

The second type of public IP address is called an Elastic IP address (EIP). This address is semi-permanent so that you can stop, start, reboot, etc. your instance without the IP address changing.